# Fetch API cannot load file:///android_asset/www/xx/xxx.json. URL scheme "file" is not supported

Tags: android, cordova, fetch-api

Using **cordova** build **Android app**, and add **cordova hot code push** plugin to make app update automatically, and using **Fetch API** to load **JSON files** which located in current project directory, the problem is when update the app, any JSON files cannot be reload,and throw the error

> Fetch API cannot load file:///android_asset/www/xx/xxx.json. URL
>   scheme "file" is not supported.

How to solve this Fecth error in Android app? Or is there any plugin that need add to my cordova project?

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/github/fetch/pull/92#issuecomment-140665932

You may use XMLHttpRequest for loading local assets.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, using `fetch()` in Android (using Cordova) uses the `file://` protocol, because of using relative URLs to fetch the resources in the Cordova app in Android, and that gives the error.

My problem was resolved by a combination of Jan's answer and the following page from the MDN web docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

In my case it had to do with the fact that using `fetch` to retrieve an audio file, I would be able to call `arrayBuffer()` on the response, but not when using the example `fetchLocal()` function that Jan links to.

The trick was needing to set the `responseType` on the XHR object.

My `fetchLocal` function looks like this:

```
function fetchLocal(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
        xhr.onload = function () {
            resolve(new Response(xhr.response, { status: xhr.status }))
        }
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject(new TypeError('Local request failed'))
        }
        xhr.open('GET', url)
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xhr.send(null)
    })
};
```

The thing that solved it for me was adding this line:

```
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

Comment: Great solution "arraybuffer" saved from a big problem.

Comment: What if you are using ```Promise```? Any ideas on how that error can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I used the code below to sidestep a similar issue with `fetch()`. I didn't want to use the code from the link in Jan's answer.

```
function fetchLocalResource(url) {        
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    req.onload = function() {
        const text = req.responseText;  
        // Do something with text...
    };    
    req.open('GET', url);
    req.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And with axios:

```
const blob = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'blob'}).then(resp => resp.data)
```