# Not able to view PDF on mobile using pdf js

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I can view a PDF in the browser using ionic serve, but I am not able to view the PDF on a device. I am testing on Android.

**This is the error I'm getting:**

```
polyfills.js:3 Fetch API cannot load file:///android_asset/www/assets/imgs/11.pdf. URL scheme “file” is not supported.
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3

vendor.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
at polyfills.js:3

at Generator._invoke (0.js:1)
at Generator.t.(anonymous function) [as next]
 (file:///android_asset/www/build/0.js:1:278295)

vendor.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): DataCloneError: Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘Worker’: TypeError: Failed to fetch could not be cloned.
Error: Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘Worker’: TypeError: Failed to fetch could not be cloned.
at o.postMessage (0.js:1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running with --livereload?

Comment: no not running with --livereload.But question us that how to view pdf which is in device file system

Comment: Understood.  There are cases where loading a file system resource does not work properly in livereload (although this is typically for `<img>` loading issues).  Please post the code you are using for opening the file.

Comment: here is my code--

 getFile(){
this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl(this.file.externalRootDirectory)
  .then((directoryEntry: DirectoryEntry) => {
  this.file.getFile(directoryEntry, '11.pdf', { create: false })
  .then((fileEntry: FileEntry) => {
      this.loadingpage(fileEntry.nativeURL); 
    });
});
}

Comment: loadingpage(url1){
  let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
let loadingTask = this.PDFJSViewer.getDocument({ url:url1, password: "test123" });
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {  
    var viewport = page.getViewport(this.scale);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
 
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

Comment: This is likely relevant for your situation.  PDFJS is likely using fetch under the covers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278371/fetch-api-cannot-load-file-android-asset-www-xx-xxx-json-url-scheme-file-i