# Fetch API cannot load file URL scheme "file" is not supported error in Cordova App

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, promise

I am on **Cordova** building an **Android app** and I am using a `Promise.all()` to load json files.

```
Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri("/faceapi/models"),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("/faceapi/models"),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("/faceapi/models"),
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri("/faceapi/models"),
    faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri("/faceapi/models")
]).then(console.log('loaded'));
```

When I run this error is thrown.

> Fetch API cannot load
> file:///faceapi/models/tiny_face_detector_model-weights_manifest.json.
> URL scheme "file" is not supported.

A more detailed breakdown of the errors in the debugger.

[image]

What is required to solve this error?

Is there an option in the Promise method I am missing?
Is there a Cordova plugin that I need?
Do I need to add any permissions to my AndroidManifest file?

This issue is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278371/fetch-api-cannot-load-file-android-asset-www-xx-xxx-json-url-scheme-file-i) but I am using the `Promise.all()` method instead.

Comment: Remove `file://`?

Comment: How would one go about that? What will I need to change in the path ```/faceapi/models```?

Comment: A string replace function?

Comment: Any code snippet of a string replace function you could guide me with?

Comment: Sorry. I know nothing of Cordova.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? @davykiash

Comment: @AlessioF Yes, I did. I placed the files on a CDN instead of locally which would have been ideal.